# Multivariate analysis for non-normal variables

Tags: r, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, nonparametric

Edit: I am trying to produce a model in R in order to analyze the relationship between several variables.  I am looking at the relationship between behaviour and dispersal of a population.  Each individual has four independently produced behavioural scores (between -25 and 25) and five different measures of how they have utilized space since their release.  I had thought a GLM would be an effective tool but the negative values in the personality mean I'm struggling to determine which distribution fits my data as ones I have used in the past don't accommodate for that.

I've researched several other statistical tests but my lack of understanding of much of the terminology has meant I've not been able to tell what would be suitable.

Currently my script is just a series of Pearson's and Spearman's tests but it feels like there has to be a better way to do this.  I freely admit statistics are not a strength of mine and if anyone has any advice on something I could try or that I might be missing I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to CV.  A variable (or a data set) cannot be parametric or non-parametricl that is a property of models. Do you mean normally distributed?           It would probably help if you describe your problem in non-statistical terms.  What are your variables? What are you trying to find out?  You might also show your code, as negative values really shouldn't be a problem for GLMs.

Comment: @PeterFlom Ah thanks for letting me know, I'll correct the post and add the information you've suggested.

Comment: OLS regression allows negative numbers and does not require normally distributed variables. It assume normally distributed errors, but that's different.